# i have been booked for a room/room has been booked

Tags: sentence

I have been booked for a room
The room has been booked.

Which sentence should I use?
And what is the difference?
For me, latter one is familiar.
Thank you so much. :)

Comment: When a person is booked they are usually spending the night in the crossbar hotel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context is needed as these describe two different scenarios.

While these sound similar, a room can be booked without you being the bookie for the room.

As such, the sentence you should choose is dependent on the context.

Comment: A bookie usually refers to one who takes gambling bets--a bookmaker.   Someone or an organization that books rooms is called a booking agent.